# Program to check if a number has a digit or is divisible by that digit's value

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

This is a game where you must count to number from 0 to 1000. However, if the number has a 6 in it, or is divisible by 6, "Shaggy" should be printed, else the number should be printed.

[**Rules:**](https://developerinsider.co/1-2-3-4-5-shaggy-programming-puzzles/)

1. You can't hard-code the numbers.
2. The number only has to satisfy at least 1 of the following requirements

   - Divisible by 6
   - Number contains a 6
3. Some type of separator is mandatory (12345Shaggy7.. doesn't count)
4. You must count exactly to 1000 from 1.
5. The numbers must be output, but it doesn't matter how (e.g., stdout, writing to a text file, etc.).

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

bool is_digitPresent(int x, int d)
{
    while (x > 0)
    {
        if (x % 10 == d)
            break;
        x = x / 10;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, n, x;
    clrscr();
    std::cout << "----------------Let's play The Shaggy Game....Are you ready..?------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Enter a number!";
    std::cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 6 == 0 || is_digitPresent(i, 6))
            std::cout << "Shaggy!\t";
        else
            std::cout << i << "\t";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `is_digitPresent` does not return anything, later using it in a boolean expression invokes undefined behavior.

You would need something like:

```
bool is_digitPresent(int x, int d)
{
    while (x > 0)        
    {                     
        if (x % 10 == d)   
            return true;   
        x = x / 10;        
    }                    
    return false;
}
```

That fixed, in main the cycle:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ /*...*/}
```

Makes litle sense as the limit for the output is the inputed number itself, just remove it for a one time execution.

If the goal is to create a loop where the program keeps asking the user for input, or you want the inputed value to have an upper limit, you need something else entirely.

Furthemore, `i` is not the value you want to test, that would be `n` which is the inputed value.

Remove the for loop en repalce it with:

```
if (n % 6 == 0 || is_digitPresent(n, 6))
    std::cout << "Shaggy!\t";
else
    std::cout << n << "\t";
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ0Byt2AL)

Note that this answer is just an error fix, some of the rules you mention are not present in it, nor is that the goal of this forum, the goal is for you to complete the exercise by yourself, with some help if needed.